# Efficiency of querying a database with STI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing, single-table-inheritance

I was curious how rails queries a table that uses STI.  For example, if my parent class is `Book` and I have two subclasses `ComicBook` and `Novel` if I do something like

```
Novel.all.each
```

since there's only one table, does the server shift through all of the comic books as well?  Is appropriate indexing automatically added to prevent this?  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can't do `Novel.each`, `each` isn't defined on model classes. You can however do `Novel.all.each ...` where `...` is some block.

As for how the query works, just call `to_sql` on any ARel expression. `Novel.all` will return the collection of models itself, so you need to go a step further to ensure a valid ARel expresion is returned by calling `scoped`.

```
[1] pry(main)> Novel.scoped.to_sql
=> "SELECT \"books\".* FROM \"books\" WHERE \"books\".\"type\" IN ('Novel')"
```

Indexing by most columns that are queried against frequently is a good thing to consider. Yes, without the index your rdbms will have to look at all records in the table as part of the above condition check.